# POWERBI - Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-datasource

I'm trying to connect oracle database using prowerbi desktop. Throwing following error

Details: "An error happened while reading data from the provider: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'"

Any idea why i see this error? I have searched it before posting here and found no clue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved - The issue is because of the versions of Oracle client and Power BI desktop.

Oracle client was 32 bit and Powerbi was 64 bit, after updating oracle client to 64 bit everything works great.

Answer (score 23):

1. Locate and copy the oraons.dll file in ‘<>product\12.2.0\client_1’ on your oracle install path
2. Paste the file into the ‘<>product\12.2.0\client_1\bin directory

Comment: Works for me, thanks. how did you find this solution? and why?

Comment: FYI: This fix is mentioned on the official PowerBI site: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-connect-oracle-database#troubleshooting

Comment: The fix info has been removed from the Official PowerBI documentation. However, it still works like a charm. Thanks Mayur!

Comment: Perfectly worked. Thanks!

Comment: Worked! Thanks! I can't believe we're still having to do this janky fix in late 2022!

Answer (score 5):

In my case, the problem was the version of Power BI, I downloaded and install it from Windows Store and the version place there got a bug.

My solution was to uninstall my PBI, download it from microsoft web page (not from Store) and install it.

https://www.microsoft.com/es-ES/download/details.aspx?id=58494

Once it's done then problem get solve.
Regards

Comment: FYI: This fix is mentioned on the official PowerBI site: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-connect-oracle-database#troubleshooting

Comment: This is so true

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue following this instruction from [Power BI Desktop troubleshooting reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-connect-oracle-database#troubleshooting):

> If you downloaded Power BI Desktop from the Microsoft Store, you might be unable to connect to Oracle databases because of an Oracle driver issue. If you encounter this issue, the error message returned is: Object reference not set. This is an issue with how Oracle driver works in Windows UWP Apps. To address the issue, you have to do the following: